# Getting the max value from a list of sums

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my version of the knapsack challenge and I was wondering if there was a way to do it so it doesn't go through the `foreach` statement so many times. At the minute it goes through it thousands of times to get he closes value to the target number, which takes long time to do, I was wondering if there was a way to either do it without `foreach` or make it quick with the `foreach`.

```
private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string input;
    string bag;
    int goal;
    int count = 0;

    int element;
    List<int> finalResult = new List<int>();
    do
    {
        bag = txtBag.Text;
    }
    while (!int.TryParse(bag, out goal));
    input = txtGenerate.Text;
    string[] elementsText = input.Split(' ');
    List<int> elementsList = new List<int>();
    foreach (string elementText in elementsText)
    {

        if (int.TryParse(elementText, out element))
        {
            elementsList.Add(element);
        }
    }
    Solver solver = new Solver();
    List<List<int>> results = solver.Solve(goal, elementsList.ToArray());
    int closestValue = 0;
    foreach (List<int> result in results)
    {
        count++;
        int totalValue = result.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));

        if (totalValue >= closestValue)
        {
            closestValue = totalValue;
            finalResult = result;
            txtSum.Text = closestValue.ToString();

        }
    }

    foreach (int value in finalResult)
    {
        txtCount.Text = count.ToString();

        cboResult.ItemsSource = finalResult;

    }
}
```

I also have a class with this in:

```
public class Solver
{
    public List<List<int>> mResults;
    public int closestValue = 0;
    public List<List<int>> Solve(int goal, int[] elements)
    {
        mResults = new List<List<int>>();
        RecursiveSolve(goal, 0, new List<int>(), new List<int>(elements), 0);
        return mResults;
    }

    private void RecursiveSolve(int goal, int currentSum,
    List<int> included, List<int> notIncluded, int startIndex)
    {
        for (int index = startIndex; index < notIncluded.Count; index++)
        {
            int nextValue = notIncluded[index];
            if (currentSum + nextValue <= goal && currentSum + nextValue >= closestValue)
            {
                List<int> newResult = new List<int>(included);
                newResult.Add(nextValue);
                mResults.Add(newResult);
                closestValue = currentSum + nextValue;
            }
            if (currentSum + nextValue < goal)
            {

                List<int> nextIncluded = new List<int>(included);
                nextIncluded.Add(nextValue);
                List<int> nextNotIncluded = new List<int>(notIncluded);
                nextNotIncluded.Remove(nextValue);
                RecursiveSolve(goal, currentSum + nextValue,
                    nextIncluded, nextNotIncluded, startIndex++);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got logic mixed in with your view.

Move as much of the code out of your button handler as you can, and into a separate function (and preferably a separate class).

A button handler should do just that, handle button presses. It should not then perform calculations.

---

Your spacing could use some work. For example:

```
    int element;
    List<int> finalResult = new List<int>();
    do
    {
        bag = txtBag.Text;
    }
    while (!int.TryParse(bag, out goal));
    input = txtGenerate.Text;
    string[] elementsText = input.Split(' ');
    List<int> elementsList = new List<int>();
    foreach (string elementText in elementsText)
    {

        if (int.TryParse(elementText, out element))
        {
            elementsList.Add(element);
        }
    }
    Solver solver = new Solver();
    List<List<int>> results = solver.Solve(goal, elementsList.ToArray());
    int closestValue = 0;
    foreach (List<int> result in results)
    {
        count++;
        int totalValue = result.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));

        if (totalValue >= closestValue)
        {
            closestValue = totalValue;
            finalResult = result;
            txtSum.Text = closestValue.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Would be a lot more readable like this:

```
    int element;
    List<int> finalResult = new List<int>();

    do
    {
        bag = txtBag.Text;
    }
    while (!int.TryParse(bag, out goal));

    input = txtGenerate.Text;
    string[] elementsText = input.Split(' ');
    List<int> elementsList = new List<int>();

    foreach (string elementText in elementsText)
    {

        if (int.TryParse(elementText, out element))
        {
            elementsList.Add(element);
        }
    }

    Solver solver = new Solver();
    List<List<int>> results = solver.Solve(goal, elementsList.ToArray());
    int closestValue = 0;

    foreach (List<int> result in results)
    {
        count++;
        int totalValue = result.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));

        if (totalValue >= closestValue)
        {
            closestValue = totalValue;
            finalResult = result;
            txtSum.Text = closestValue.ToString();

        }
    }
```

---

Use `var` when it is obvious from the RHS of a declaration what the type of the variable is, and **always** use var in foreach loops.

e.g.

```
    int element;
    var finalResult = new List<int>();

    do
    {
        bag = txtBag.Text;
    }
    while (!int.TryParse(bag, out goal));

    input = txtGenerate.Text;
    var elementsText = input.Split(' ');
    var elementsList = new List<int>();

    foreach (var elementText in elementsText)
    {

        if (int.TryParse(elementText, out element))
        {
            elementsList.Add(element);
        }
    }

    var solver = new Solver();
    List<List<int>> results = solver.Solve(goal, elementsList.ToArray());
    var closestValue = 0;

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        count++;
        int totalValue = result.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));

        if (totalValue >= closestValue)
        {
            closestValue = totalValue;
            finalResult = result;
            txtSum.Text = closestValue.ToString();
        }
    }
```

---

Avoid Hungarian notation in C#, and prefer public properties over public fields. Additionally, public collections should be readonly, and you don't need to intiialize an integer as 0. Its default value is 0.

```
    private readonly List<List<int>> results

    public List<List<int>> Results 
    {
        get 
        {
            return results;
        }
    }

    public int ClosestValue {get; set;}
```

Comment: "prefer public properties over public fields" Yes, but also prefer private fields over both. I don't see any reason why those should be public here.

Comment: Very good point.

Answer (score 3):

WPF is not WinForms. You should look into how binding works in WPF and into the MVVM pattern.

---

```
string input;
string bag;
int goal;
int count = 0;
```

You shouldn't declare your variables at the start of the method like this. Declare them when you need them.

---

```
do
{
    bag = txtBag.Text;
}
while (!int.TryParse(bag, out goal));
```

If I understand this code correctly, If `txtBag` contains a valid `int`, it will set its value to the `goal` variable, otherwise it will loop forever. That might be okay if you're writing a Turing machine, but not if you're writing a real program. If the goal was to give the user a chance to fix incorrect input, then this code doesn't achieve it.

---

```
if (int.TryParse(elementText, out element))
{
    elementsList.Add(element);
}
```

In production code, invalid input should cause an error, not be silently ignored.

---

```
List<List<int>> results = solver.Solve(goal, elementsList.ToArray());
```

Why does `Solver` return some (?!) valid combinations and not just the best one?

---

```
count++;
```

Why are you computing this, when you could just use `results.Count`?

---

```
result.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
```

`result` is already a collection of `int`s, there is no need for a conversion.

---

To find the maximum value, you need to iterate over all the values. But you can at least simplify your code by using `MaxBy()` from [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

---

With the suggestions above, this part of your code could look like this:

```
if (results.Any())
{
    var closest = results
        .Select(result => new { result, totalValue = result.Sum() })
        .MaxBy(x => x.totalValue);

    closestValue = closest.totalValue;
    finalResult = closest.result;
    txtSum.Text = closestValue.ToString();
}
```

---

```
foreach (int value in finalResult)
{
    txtCount.Text = count.ToString();

    cboResult.ItemsSource = finalResult;
}
```

There is no reason for this to be a loop.

---

```
public class Solver
public List<List<int>> Solve(int goal, int[] elements)
```

Those are not very good names, they don't say anything about what are they actually solving.

---

`elementsList` is a `List`, that's converted to array using `ToArray()` (a copy) and then back to `List` inside `Solve()` using `new List` (another copy), that's unnecessary.

---

The way you're working with `included` and `notIncluded` means you're creating lots of copies. You might want to consider using one of [the immutable collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn769092).